# Trouble with EditText inside a (Sherlock)Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

Hey Everyone,
             I am having some trouble with my edit texts in my Fragment. I get a NUllPointerException on the EditText.getText().toString(). I know there are a few similar threads on this but I have had not luck fixing my problem. I have tried putting the (EditText) getView().findViewById(...) both the in the onCreateView() and in the onActivityCreated() and still I get the NullPointerException.

I have attached (what I think is) the relevant code. Let me know if you need to see any more of the code.
The NullPointerException is in the Intent createShareIntent() method. I have commented the line where I get the exception.

```
public class EditNoteFragment extends SherlockFragment {

Long mCurrentPosition;
EditText title;
EditText body;


    // in a fragment class this does not do anything.
    // it is mostly here to register for the menu and context menu. that is all
    // seems silly :/ 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getLong("RowId");
        }

     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_note, container, false);

        title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        //title.setText("");
         body = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
        // body.setText("");


     return view;
}
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem menuShare = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
    ShareActionProvider shareAction = (ShareActionProvider) 
         menuShare.getActionProvider();
    shareAction.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
}

protected Intent createShareIntent() {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title.getText().toString()); // From logcat I can see the NullPointerException here
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.getText().toString());
    return shareIntent;
}
```

As requested the relevant xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="@string/titlehint"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/noteshint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Show us the relevant XML. I think you messed up the proper EditText ID

Comment: Hey, thanks to having a look.Just added the xml. There is nothing to it, it is just 2 edit texts.

Comment: @AstralProjection I changed the layout to FrameLayout and added and android:id element to it. Did not make a difference. have a look at the ans below and my comment to it. Thanks for helping out, cheers.

Comment: Oh I answered that on a different tangent, however check if you get the value of edit text somewhere else outside of SharedIntent function. just System.out.println() it out without calling the function for debug purpose. Also double check your XML file name, if you are referencing the same file or some other file?

Comment: The XML file is fine. I did 2 tests just now:

Comment: Mail me your project at j.sakib03@gmail.com

Comment: Hey, sorry about the delayed reply. I scattered a few log statements(Log.w("Rakshak", "in the on activity created"))  around; the onCreateView is not getting called at all.Any idea why this is?

Comment: mailing code right now. it is not very clean, I am just learning fragments and trying to make an app using fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this.

```
if(title!=null){
    final String text = title.getText();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        // creates the intent and fires it...
    } else {
        // shows an error message that the text is required.
    }
```

}

Is is bound to work

Answer (score 0):

The method of [EditText.getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) retrieves an object of kind [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) only if the edit text contains any text field inside (Editable is the product of the text filled by the user in the box with graphical properties).

You should do the following:

```
final String text = title.getText() != null ? title.getText().toString() : null;
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
    // creates the intent and fires it...

} else {
    // shows an error message that the text is required.
}
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks man for helping out man. I used a similar solution from the guy below. Cheers.